# IAM permission for EC2 Data Lifecycle Manager is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I have created an IAM user in my AWS account. IAM user requires permission to access Amazon data Lifecycle Manager. I had given the following permissions to the IAM user

- *AmazonEC2FullAccess*,
- *AWSDataLifecycleManagerServiceRole*
- and *AWSDataLifecycleManagerServiceRoleForAMIManagement*.

But when I tried to access Amazon Data Lifecycle Manager with this IAM user account, I get this following statement on the lifecycle manager page

> It is taking a bit longer than usual to fetch your data.

(The page keepy on loading for a longer period of time)

This message doesn't appear when I tried to access the same page with the same IAM user but this time with Administrator-Access.
[image: please click here to see the attached screenshot]

Can somebody please let me know what's going wrong here, because I want to grant limited permission for my IAM user to manage my AWS resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policies that you mencioned does not include permissions to access Data Lifecycle Manager.

This is another service that is not included on EC2 (this is why AmazonEC2FullAccess does not give you permissions). Additionally, AWSDataLifecycleManagerServiceRole and AWSDataLifecycleManagerServiceRoleForAMIManagement are managed policies to allow AWS Data Lifecycle Manager itself to take actions on AWS resources. So these policies should not be applied to IAM Users.

You need to create a custom IAM Policy with the proper permissions. In case of read only you can use this:

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
            "Sid": "DataLifecycleManagerRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dlm:Get*",
                "dlm:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

To create policies through web console, some additional permissions are required because the web shows more information to help during creation process. So in order to have enough permissions to create policies via web use this (some of these are referenced on [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dlm-access-control.html) but seems to be incomplete):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dlm:*",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshots",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:EnableFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:DescribeFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:DisableFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:CopySnapshot",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshotAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:DeleteRule",
                "events:DescribeRule",
                "events:EnableRule",
                "events:DisableRule",
                "events:ListTargetsByRule",
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:RemoveTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/AwsDataLifecycleRule.managed-cwe.*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Omar Rosadio, Thanks for taking your time and replying. I tried the above policy and it's working fine. I followed your instructions and tried to create custom policy as given below, but I was not able to create any lifecycle policy, I can only view it.

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dlm:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I would be glad if you can help me with creating full permissions for using Data Lifecycle Manager to my IAM user.

Comment: I have just updated the answer. Try with that policy

Comment: Hi @Omar Rosadio, I appreciate and thankyou for taking your time and helping me.
I followed your instructions to create a DLM AMI policy but during the last step of creation, I got an error saying "I dont have required permission to Create and Attach the default role". So I tried to change the policy by adding these permission "IAMCreateRole" & IAMAttachRole" and it worked.

Once Again Thanks for your Help!

Comment: I have updated the answer with the missing permissions. Please mark the answer as accepted to help others with the same problem